# Bootstrap's "tab-content" not working in Asp.Net MVCP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a tabbed login page, so that the user can either log-in or click on other tabs for other info. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Log-in</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aboutus">What's HooHit?</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#howworks">How it works!</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>


            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <h3>HOME</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="aboutus" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>HooHit Logo</h3>
                    <p>HooHit Pets is an online community...</p>
                </div>
                <div id="howworks" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Steps picture</h3>
                    <p>You simply upload a picture or video ...</p>
                </div>
                <div id="blog" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <br />
                    <p>...</p>
                    <a href="https://blog.hoohit.com">Click here!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is that when I run the code, the tabs don't work. So when I click on the blog tab as an example, the URL on the browser changes to http://localhost:43345/Account/Login2#blog but the tab doesn't change in the view. I can guess the reasoning (i.e. routing in MVC) but am not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is correct.
You might be missing a Jquery reference needed by boostrap in your page.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, your answer did the trick. Turns out that I was setting the layout page to null and so any reference to bootstrap was being removed (the jquery reference was there though). So as soon as I added the bootstrap reference, it did the trick. Much appreciated!